# JavaScript not calling properly when uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

The below code is currently uploaded to https://katiedeanjewel.staging.wpengine.com/checkout/#. It targets the checkout page.

Note the checkout content does not load if you do not have an item in the cart.

When I copy/paste this exact code into my console, it is fine.

When it is on the server (on a WordPress site), the event event listener does not fire. The `trigger` element is prorperly logged, so the script is running fine.

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
(function() {
console.log("lux_script.js");

var trigger = $("#billing_continue");
console.log(trigger);

$(trigger).on("click", function() { shippingScript() } );


function shippingScript() {
    console.log("ShippingScript");

    var select = $("#shipping_country")[0];
    var shipping = $("#shipping_option_select select")[0];

    //international shipping option 
    var world = $(shipping).children("option[value='woocommerce_flatrate_percountry']")[0];

    // domestic shipping options
    var shipOpts = $(shipping).children("option:not([value='woocommerce_flatrate_percountry'])");
    shipOpts = $.makeArray(shipOpts);

    function showDomestics() {
        console.log("showDomestics");
        $(shipOpts).show();
    }

    function hideDomestics() {
        console.log("hideDomestics");
        var _select = $("#shipping_country")[0];
        $(shipOpts).hide();
        var selected = $(_select).children("option:selected")[0];

        if ( $.inArray(selected, shipOpts) ) {
            $(selected).removeAttr("selected");
            $(world).attr("selected", "selected");
        } else {
            console.log("not in array");
        }
    }

    $(select).on("change", function() {
        console.log("changing to a different country")
        var selected = $(this).children("option:selected");

        $(selected).val() === 'US' ? showDomestics() : hideDomestics();
    });
}

})();
```

Comment: Try wrapping the interior of each function with try{ } catch  logic, that if there is an error at least you will be told....put in your catch alert(ex); and catch(ex)

Comment: No need to do that - uncaught exceptions are being printed in the browser's developer tools within console, e.g. in Chrome or Firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you wrap all you code in this format that I have included below for WordPress scripts.

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function() {
        var trigger = $("#billing_continue");
        console.log(trigger);

        $(trigger).on("click", function() { shippingScript() } );


        function shippingScript() {
            console.log("ShippingScript");

            var select = $("#shipping_country")[0];
            var shipping = $("#shipping_option_select select")[0];

            //international shipping option 
            var world = $(shipping).children("option[value='woocommerce_flatrate_percountry']")[0];

            // domestic shipping options
            var shipOpts = $(shipping).children("option:not([value='woocommerce_flatrate_percountry'])");
            shipOpts = $.makeArray(shipOpts);

            function showDomestics() {
                console.log("showDomestics");
                $(shipOpts).show();
            }

            function hideDomestics() {
                console.log("hideDomestics");
                var _select = $("#shipping_country")[0];
                $(shipOpts).hide();
                var selected = $(_select).children("option:selected")[0];

                if ( $.inArray(selected, shipOpts) ) {
                    $(selected).removeAttr("selected");
                    $(world).attr("selected", "selected");
                } else {
                    console.log("not in array");
                }
            }

            $(select).on("change", function() {
                console.log("changing to a different country")
                var selected = $(this).children("option:selected");

                $(selected).val() === 'US' ? showDomestics() : hideDomestics();
            });
        }
    });

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is not found on your page, try to run this in the console:

```
$("#billing_continue").length
```

It returns 0, what means that the element is not present.

In addition, check if you are not redirected to:
http://katiedeanjewel.staging.wpengine.com/cart/#

If object with id `billing_continue` is loaded dynamically, you should use:

```
$(document).on("click", "#billing_continue", function() { shippingScript() } );
```

Comment: The trigger is found and logged. I should mention that if there is not an item in the cart, the page content does not load.